# grep n lines from file with n being extracted from the same file

Tags: bash, grep

I want to: 
1) extract an integer N from a *file* standing by a specific key-phrase, e.g. 'no of lines'
2) grep N lines after another specific phrase, say 'start from here', i.e.:

Input *file*

```
no of lines 8
.....
start from here
0.6250000000    1  O         1
0.8750000000    1  O         2
0.1250000000    1  O         3
0.3750000000    1  O         4
0.6250000000    1  O         5
0.8750000000    1  O         6
0.1250000000    1  O         7
0.3750000000    1  O         8
.....
```

Output:

```
start from here
0.6250000000    1  O         1
0.8750000000    1  O         2
0.1250000000    1  O         3
0.3750000000    1  O         4
0.6250000000    1  O         5
0.8750000000    1  O         6
0.1250000000    1  O         7
0.3750000000    1  O         8
```

Thought something like this would do:

```
N=`grep 'no of lines' file| tr -d A-Za-z' '`
grep -A $N 'start from here'
```

but apparently grep doesn't allow to pass arguments this way.

Thanks for helping.

PS. No need to stick to grep.

UPDATE:
The file I was working on was actually a DOS file, which I did not know. This caused all troubles. So in fact, all proposed solutions, including mine (corrected):

```
tr -d '\r' < file > file_n
N=`grep 'no of lines' file_n| tr -d A-Za-z' '`
grep -A $N 'start from here' file_n
```

work just fine.

Comment: Can you provide a sample input & output?

Comment: Do you have to grep it, or are you open to using Python or something?

Comment: `bash` replaces `$N` with its value before `grep` is called, so `grep` doesn't know a variable was being used. The problem must lie in how you set the value of `N`.

Comment: On what system are you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will be much easier with awk:

```
awk '/^no of lines/{N=$NF; next} /^start from here/{s=1; i=0}
         s && i<=N{print; i++; next} {s=0}' file
start from here
0.6250000000    1  O         1
0.8750000000    1  O         2
0.1250000000    1  O         3
0.3750000000    1  O         4
0.6250000000    1  O         5
0.8750000000    1  O         6
0.1250000000    1  O         7
0.3750000000    1  O         8
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course `grep` allows passing arguments this way(because it does not even know whether a variable was passed or just a plain text).

The problem with your script is that you just haven't specified the filename for the second `grep` command. Here is a bit better version of your script that works correctly:

```
n=$(grep -Pom 1 'no of lines \K[0-9]+' yourfile)
grep -A "$n" 'start from here' yourfile
```

Comment: Works, thanks! The problem wasn't in the missing file name though (just forgot to copy it here), but in the way I recalled 'N'. I was missing double quotation marks in "$N".

Comment: @rarpas nope, quotation marks don't matter here, because your ``$N`` variable would be a single integer anyway. As already mentioned the problem was in the way you set ``N``

Comment: true, the way you set `N` doesn't care if the file is dos or unix, hence it worked for my dos file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `xargs` to redirect the results from the first call to `grep` to the second call:

```
grep 'no of lines' file|tr -d A-Za-z' '|xargs grep 'start from here' file -A
```

Comment: still getting ': invalid context length argument'

Comment: Why not? Simplicity is relative.

Comment: @rarpas Strange, this perfectly works for me on both Ubuntu 12.04 and Mac OS X 10.9.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk

```
awk '/^no of lines/{N=$NF} 
     /^start from here/{for(i=1;i<=N+1;i++) {print;getline}}' file
```